# When you await on async call--is it really asynchronous programming in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have three tier .net web api application. each tier is implementing a async method. Each call is `async` and and we are using `await` at each step. **My question** is when you `await` at every step, doesn't it make the application synchronous & defeats the purpose ? What value async await really provides? Does it automatically uses multiple CPU cores?

Controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    return Ok(await _service.Create());
}
```

middle tier:

```
public async Task<MyObject> Create()
{
    return await _repository.CreateAsync(new MyDataObject());
}
```

DB

```
public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T data)
{
    var o = _dbSet.Add(data);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: async != multithreading (in case that's the thinking that led to your questions).

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama : Thank you for the comment but I am not thinking of multithreading here . I am just thinking about benefits of async await

Comment: If you're not thinking of multithreading, why do you think that it might automatically use multiple CPU cores?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: Since I could not see any value addition by async methods here. that made me think does it runs on new thread ?

Comment: Consider this example (numbers are just made up): you have 10 threads to process web requests on a server. Most of the time you want to talk to a database or make web requests to APIs, accessing files, etc. (IO-bound operations). If you talk to the database/external API/file system synchronously, then you're basically blocking a thread while you wait for the IO operations, meaning that that thread can't be used to process another web request in the meantime. With async, no thread is blocked while waiting for IO to complete, so other requests can be handled. When IO comes back, a thread is used

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: so is async() == multiple threads ? You block main thread and do rest of the things in another thread? My question is off topic. Does using async await at every steps does it makes the program synchronous ?

Comment: The functions you show in your question are themselves async. There's nothing preventing you from executing these functions concurrently with other code by some means.

These functions are awaiting their internal async calls because their results depend on those calls. E.g. `Get()` awaits `_service.Create()` because its return value is 100% dependent on the result of `_service.Create()`, so it must wait for it to complete. But `Get()` leaves the possibility that you, the programmer, may wish to execute `Get()` concurrently alongside other async functions.

Comment: @OpenStack It doesn't block the "main" thread, it suspends it until the IO-bound work is complete, and then when the IO-bound work is done, it assigns a thread pool thread to it to continue execution with of the code after the `await` keyword. Blocking implies that the main thread is still running and waiting, but this is not the case. I'd suggest taking a look at Stephen Cleary's blogs on async in C# to get a better understanding of it (it really helped me): https://blog.stephencleary.com/

Comment: No, async does *not* mean multiple threads. You can get the benefits of async with a single thread. Continuing on ProgrammingLlama's example, if you only have a single thread, and that single thread is blocked waiting for I/O (database, network, or disc operations) then that single thread can be freed up to be used elsewhere, thus while it doesn't improve the speed of any one operation, it does allow more to be done because your threads aren't just sitting there waiting.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama: Last statement made lot of sense to me. With `async await` Thread is not `blocked`, instead it is `suspended` and added back to thread pool. once `(a)wait` is over, you get another thread to continue execution. Beautiful.

Comment: I kindly remind to all participants that the comments are intended for asking for clarifications about the question, or suggesting improvements for the question, not for answering the question.

Answer (score 5):

In your example you're definitely doing *asynchronous* processing. What you're not doing is *parallel* processing. The .NET documentation doesn't always do a good job of differentiating between the two. I'll just cover asynchronous here.

The main idea behind `async` / `await` (which your examples do well) is to not have a thread sitting around doing nothing when it could be doing something useful.

Take your `CreateAsync` example:

```
public async Task<T> CreateAsync(T data)
{
    var o = _dbSet.Add(data);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return 100;
}
```

The database changes won't happen any faster because of the `await`. So what's the benefit? For the sake of argument assume the following:

- Your app has 5 users
- Your app has 2 threads available (way low, but play along)
- Each database save takes 3 seconds

Now assume User A and User B save a record at the same time. Each has their own thread (that's a fact, not an assumption). If you aren't using `await` then users A and B will hold both of your available threads for 3 seconds just waiting for the save to complete. No more threads are available, so users C, D and E will be blocked for that period.

When you use `await`, the threads are released because they're just... waiting. Now they can take care of users C, D, and E. When the save completes the threads will come back for users A and B and finish the `CreateAsync` method.

Bottom line, when `async` / `await` is done properly *n* threads can fulfill way more than *n* requests.

This is a simplified explanation, but I really wish I'd gotten a simple explanation way back when. I hope this helps.

Comment: Makes sense. This makes me wonder, during waiting period when thread is freed, who is completing the task of dealing with DB ?

Comment: The db write is sent; the db is doing the write; there's no sense in blocking an API thread just waiting for the db to respond. Also see [intro to async on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net) and [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), both by yours truly.

Comment: Great question! I left out a lot of detail on purpose because that's what the `await` / `async` implementation does too: it shields us from the gory details. Time for the next level: when I said the app had two threads I meant two *worker* threads, which do the actual work. There's also a main thread that manages all the workers. That's the one that notes when the waiting DB operation has a reply and fires up another worker thread (as soon as it's available) to finish the method.

Comment: @StephenCleary I wish I'd seen your articles years ago. I blush to think how long it took for async to click with me. I read reams of articles but they always managed to pollute the explanations with discursions into parallel processing or dive straight into details better left until later, leaving me thoroughly confused. Thanks so much for those links.

Comment: You're right @TheodorZoulias. Answer edited. I wanted to say more about how it reduces delays if there are > *n+1* users, but a good artist should know when to stop :). Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

> What value async await really provides?

It allows your web server to process more requests at the same time; `async/await` allows the threads to do other work while the code waits for the db to do its work (db or cache, email service, external api call, etc.).

From [Async Programming : Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net):

> (...) let’s say the requests in the system depend on some external resource, like a database or Web API. When a request comes in, ASP.NET takes one of its thread pool threads and assigns it to that request. Because it’s written synchronously, the request handler will call that external resource synchronously. This blocks the request thread until the call to the external resource returns.
>
> ...
>
> Asynchronous request handlers operate differently. When a request comes in, ASP.NET takes one of its thread pool threads and assigns it to that request. This time the request handler will call that external resource asynchronously. This returns the request thread to the thread pool until the call to the external resource returns.

Answer (score 1):

When you await an async method in C#, it does not necessarily mean that the method is executed asynchronously. It simply means that the calling method will be suspended until the awaited task completes.

The async and await keywords in C# are used to simplify the process of writing asynchronous code. They allow you to write code that looks and reads like synchronous code, while still being asynchronous under the hood.

To understand how async and await work, it is important to know that an async method actually returns a Task or Task object, which represents the asynchronous operation. The await operator is used to suspend the execution of the calling method until the awaited Task completes.

However, just because a method is marked async does not necessarily mean that it will be executed asynchronously. The actual execution of the method depends on how the Task is implemented and whether it is running on a thread pool thread or not.

For example, if the Task is running on a ThreadPool thread, it will be executed asynchronously. On the other hand, if the Task is implemented using the Task.Run method, it will be executed synchronously on a separate ThreadPool thread.

In short, the async and await keywords in C# allow you to write asynchronous code that is easier to read and maintain, but they do not guarantee that the code will be executed asynchronously.

Comment: *"if the Task is running on a `ThreadPool` thread, it will be executed asynchronously. On the other hand, if the Task is implemented using the `Task.Run` method, it will be executed synchronously on a separate `ThreadPool` thread."* -- I don't get the difference. In both cases a `ThreadPool` thread will do the work, so why one case is asynchronous and the other is not?

Answer (score 1):

> Each call is `async` and and we are using `await` at each step. **My question** is when you `await` at every step, doesn't it make the application synchronous & defeats the purpose?

First of all, synchronous and asynchronous is a property of a method or an execution flow, not a property of the application as a whole. In your case you `await` on every level and every step all asynchronous operations (`Task`s) that you start, so the execution flow of each web request is asynchronous. It's still a single execution flow though. The code is executed in a sequential/serialized fashion. In the context of a single web request, no concurrency is happening.

The difference from a classic and familiar synchronous execution flow is that the flow is not forced to run on the same thread from start to finish. Different threads might be involved in the execution, but not more than one thread at the same time. A thread-switch might occur at each `await` point, and whether it will happen depends on various factors that might not be under your direct control. The most interesting aspect of an asynchronous flow is that, time-wise, large parts of the execution are usually not running on any thread. For example while the `_dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()` is doing its job, there is [no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) in your process that is blocked waiting for this work to be done. This means that your web application can have a large number of concurrent executions flows (web requests), using only a small number of threads. Which eventually results in increased scalability for your application: you can serve more users with less hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Relatively new developers who come to asynchronous programming directly using `async/await` may have this confusion. To understand and appreciate the value of what `async/await` brings to table, one has to go slightly back in time and review how asynchronous code was written then.

Before the keywords were introduced in C#, asynchronous programming was still possible. Traditionally (.NET Framework 2.0 later), there were two patterns:

Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP), where you subscribed to an event:

```
o.ReadCompleted += (o, e) => { // asynchronously called after ReadAsync completion }; 
o.ReadAsync(buffer, count); // begin the async process
```

Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP), which is Promise like interface where you can setup completions with `then` and `catch`.

```
o.ReadAsync(buffer, count)
  .then( (result) => { // asynchronously called after ReadAsync completion } );
```

So, advantage of asynchronous programming on the server is that the calling thread is not blocked on the `Read`, which is now an asynchronous call as against a synchronous call. The thread can do some other tasks / or serve other requests.

When I/O bound `Read` eventually completes, the completion delegate will be called, possibly over a different thread. This way there are more threads available which makes the service more scalable. This is advantage of asynchronous programming.

However, the two patterns above have a disadvantage for the developer that the code becomes `unreadable` and `inside-out` because it is not written sequentially.

The `async`/`await` keywords just let us keep the same advantages of asynchronous programming, while making the code readable.

Now we just write:

```
var result = await o.ReadAsync(buffer, count);
// here comes code that we had to previously write inside the completion delegate
// but now its more readable, and much natural to handle exceptions
```

So although it looks sequential to developer it is still asynchronous. The compiler converts the `async` method into a *state machine* which behaves similar to code previously written, but hides away all the complex details from the developer. Similar to the completion delegate behavior, the code written after `await` could also be resumed on a different thread.